# MapView в фрагменте НЕ ЗАГРУЖАЕТ карту

Tags: android, android-fragment, google-maps-api

fragment_maps.xml

```html
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

FragmetnMap.java

```js
public class Maps extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;
    private static final String MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";

    MapView mMapView;
    GoogleMap map;

    public static Maps newInstance() {
        Maps fragment = new Maps();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflat and return the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }
        mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);

        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
            outState.putBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        }
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mMapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        LatLng ekat = new LatLng(56.8519000, 60.6122000);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ekat));
        map.setMinZoomPreference(15);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(getActivity(), map);

       /* try {
            readItems();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Problem reading list of markers.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }



   /* private void readItems() throws JSONException {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.geojson);
        List<MyItem> items = new MyItemReader().read(inputStream);
        mClusterManager.addItems(items);
    }*/
}
```

Может уже кто то сталкивался с подобной задачей. В чем может быть проблема? или есть идеи?!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Проблема заключалась в ключе Api. Создал новый проект с новым ключем и карта заработала.